# Thrown error gets caught in the wrong catch

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling, try-catch, realm

I'm using Realm in my app. I'm trying a implement a unified error handling interface for all types of errors. For example, I have a class that handles all `User` related tasks. So I have an enum called `UserError`.

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

enum UserError: Error {
    case doesNotExist
    case alreadyExists
    case databaseError(error: Error)
}

class UserHelper {

    /// Fetch user object for the given email if exists.
    func getUser(forEmail email: String) throws -> User {
        do {
            guard let user = try Realm().object(ofType: User.self, forPrimaryKey: email) else {
                throw UserError.doesNotExist
            }

            return user
        } catch {
            throw UserError.databaseError(error: error)
        }
    }

}
```

I have a separate catch-all `databaseError` enum value to catch all Realm related errors.

The problem with my method is, when I throw the `doesNotExist` error inside the `do-catch` where I query the database, that error gets caught inside *this* method's `catch` and gets re-thrown as a `databaseError`. I want the error to arrive as the original type, `doesNotExist`.

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `catch` clause is unqualified and therefore catches every error thrown within the `do` clause, whether or not it's a Realm error or a `UserError`. You can try making the catch clause conditional, since you only want to throw a `databaseError()` if the error is indeed a Realm error:

```
do {
    guard let user = try Realm().object(ofType: User.self, forPrimaryKey: email) else {
        throw UserError.doesNotExist
    }
    return user
} catch let error as Realm.Error {
    throw UserError.databaseError(error: error)
}
```

If you do this, you can also change your `UserError.databaseError` case to take a `Realm.Error` instead of a plain `Error`, giving whatever code catches your error more information about the specific database error.